# how to pass array from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

how to pass array(below) from view to controller in codeigniter

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PersonalID] => 1111111111111
            [EmployeeSalary] => 20000
            [EmployeeContrib] => 750
        )
```

`[1] => Array
    (
        [PersonalID] => 2222222222222
        [EmployeeSalary] => 10000
        [EmployeeContrib] => 500
    )`

)

Comment: and why do you need to pass `view data` --> to `controller`? it should be the other way around

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to pass data from view to controller then,
first convert your array to json string $jsonString= json_encode($data),store that string in hidden form field and post that value in controller,in controller just decode json using json_decode($jsonString) it will give array.

```
$data = array(
                0 => array(
                 'PersonalID' => '1111111111111',
               'EmployeeSalary' => '20000',
               'EmployeeContrib' => '750'

                ),
                1 => array(
                 'PersonalID' => '1111111111111',
               'EmployeeSalary' => '20000',
               'EmployeeContrib' => '750'

            )
          );
    $jsonString= json_encode($data) ;
```

in controller

```
$array=json_decode($jsonString);
print_r($array);
```